# grease pencil edit mode simplify stroke in python

Tags: python, edit-mode, grease-pencil

Can someone can help me to simplify a stroke in grease pencil edit mode?

I'm looking for the equivalent of this command used on curves:

[image: Screen shot showing simply command for curves]

but in Python and for Grease Pencil objects.

Answer (score 2):

---

UPDATE: The original question has been clarified in a comment on my answer.  This answers the question in the comment.

If you already have a Grease Pencil object set up then you can simply call [`stroke_simplify`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.gpencil.html#bpy.ops.gpencil.stroke_simplify) with that object selected:

```py
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.data.objects['Stroke'].select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = object
bpy.ops.gpencil.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.gpencil.stroke_simplify()
```

This assumes you are starting in object mode.

---

EDIT: I've left the original answer, in case anyone has a need for it.

Grease pencil is a bit complex, even as bpy subsystems go, so you may want to watch the tutorial series that starts with [this video](https://youtu.be/csQNmnc5xQg) before you try working with Grease pencil in Python.

Basically, before you can draw you need to create a `GPencil` object, configure it, and give it one or more materials.  Then you can draw strokes on that object.  Here's an example, taken from the tutorial:

```py
gpencil_data = bpy.data.grease_pencils.new("GPencil")
gpencil = bpy.data.objects.new(gpencil_data.name, gpencil_data)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(gpencil)

gp_layer = gpencil_data.layers.new("lines")

gp_frame = gp_layer.frames.new(bpy.context.scene.frame_current)

gp_stroke = gp_frame.strokes.new()
gp_stroke.line_width = 12
gp_stroke.start_cap_mode = 'ROUND'
gp_stroke.end_cap_mode = 'ROUND'
gp_stroke.use_cyclic = True

pts = [(0.0, 0.0, -1.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (-1.0, 0.0, -0.5), (0.5, 0.0, -0.5)]

gp_stroke.points.add(len(pts))

for item, value in enumerate(pts):
    gp_stroke.points[item].co = value
    
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Black")
bpy.data.materials.create_gpencil_data(mat)
gpencil.data.materials.append(mat)
mat.grease_pencil.show_fill = True
mat.grease_pencil.fill_color = (1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
mat.grease_pencil.color = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)

gp_stroke.points[0].pressure = 10
gp_stroke.points[0].vertex_color = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
gp_stroke.points[-1].pressure = 10
gp_stroke.points[-1].vertex_color = (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

If you run the example, it will create an object, `GPencil`, and then draw some strokes in it, resulting in this:

[image: Result of running script]

This is a bit confusing, because the code doesn't generate a *Stroke* material, so Blender defaults to a Blue color, and while the code generates a material that it calls `Black`, it doesn't set the material properties, so it ends up with a pink material for the *Fill*.

Comment: thank's @MartyFouts, 
I think I phrased my question wrong, I need to simplify the grease pencil stroke in edit-mode
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/886596110561456169/980102763675537448/smpl_strk.png?width=629&height=466

Comment: call [`stroke_simplify()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.gpencil.html#bpy.ops.gpencil.stroke_simplify) on the selected closed curve.  You don't need the for loop in your example because you've only got one gpencil object selected.